# How to prevent ion-item-sliding close on tap?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When I tap/click on sliding option it returns to the original state. How to disable return on click for it?

```
<ion-item-sliding #item>
    <ion-item>
        something here
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
        It closes if tap here
    </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```